# Get the camera position in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

I know that in opengl that the camera doesn't move, but the model is moving around it. Well I need the position of the camera in `MODELVIEW`... Yes, I also know that there is many topics about it but I tried all what they are doing to get the camera coordinates but it always returns `(0, 0, 0)` (the real position of the camera).

This is what i'm trying :

```
GLfloat mdl[16];
float camera_org[3];
glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
glPushMatrix();
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, mdl);
camera_org[0] = -(mdl[0] * mdl[12] + mdl[1] * mdl[13] + mdl[2] * mdl[14]);
camera_org[1] = -(mdl[4] * mdl[12] + mdl[5] * mdl[13] + mdl[6] * mdl[14]);
camera_org[2] = -(mdl[8] * mdl[12] + mdl[9] * mdl[13] + mdl[10] * mdl[14]);
```

also tried this (as said in some topics) :

```
camera_org[0] = mdl[12];
camera_org[0] = mdl[13];
camera_org[0] = mdl[14];
```

both of them gives me the same result `(0,0,0)`, can anyone please tell me what i'm doing wrong ??

Comment: you are using the deprecated fixed function pipeline

Comment: I'm only a beginner in opengl, can you please explain more

Comment: This very much sounds like you are trying to do something that def is wrong idea to try to do. You probably should rethink what you actually try to archive and if there was better alternative. To have something sane in GL matrix stack you would need to set it your self.

Comment: I found a better way to do it, I posted the answer, thank you !

Comment: Actually there's no camera at all in OpenGL. If you have a camera object in your logic, then get its position from there. Do not treat OpenGL like a scene graph, because OpenGL is not a scene graph.

Comment: What I (and many other people) call Camera is the position from wich the image given is seen, I needed to draw something just besides this position (something that will folow me when i'm looking at the scene)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer for this :

```
int viewport[4]; 
// get matrixs and viewport:
glGetDoublev( GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, matModelView ); 
glGetDoublev( GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, matProjection ); 
glGetIntegerv( GL_VIEWPORT, viewport ); 
gluUnProject( (viewport[2]-viewport[0])/2 , (viewport[3]-viewport[1])/2, 
0.0, matModelView, matProjection, viewport,  
&camera_pos[0],&camera_pos[1],&camera_pos[2]);
```

this will give you the coordinates of the camera in the scene.

Comment: Actually what this gives you is the transformation part of the modelview matrix currently on top of the stack. You can get exactly the same result (given that you don't do crazy stuff with the projection matrix) by looking at the 4th column of the modelview matrix (and flip the sign).

Comment: Michael IV, can you point provide a pointer to API should be used instead? Otherwise people reading this just know what not to do - which makes unhappy and triggers enhanced coffee consumption :(

Comment: why doesnt it only has 3 elements ? whats the fourth of viewport ? can you please explain ?

Comment: my compiler says matModelView undeclared and matProjection undeclared, how should I get them ?

Comment: Hi @user7185318 the code asumes you have them declared before. you can use double matModelView[16] for instance.

Comment: Ah, sorry, thanks for the help, I didnt really concentrate while reading through, when implementing I checked it out.

Comment: Isn't this giving you the unprojected 3d location of the centre of the screen, rather than the 3d unprotected camera focal point?